# How to draw a photo then a shape on top of the photo using a canvas in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, html5-canvas, ionic4

There are numerous examples out there showing how to draw things onto a canvas, however, my problem is slightly different - I want to load a photo into memory, draw a shape onto exact coordinates over the photo, THEN draw/scale the photo onto a canvas. Not sure where to start with this. Are there any relevant libraries out there I can use with ionic that will allow you to do this?

**Edit 1** ~ I now have this mostly working:

private properties:

```
@ViewChild('mainCanvas') canvasEl: ElementRef;
private _CANVAS: any;
private _CONTEXT: any;
```

ionViewDidEnter():

```
this._CANVAS = this.canvasEl.nativeElement;
this._CONTEXT = this._CANVAS.getContext('2d');
```

updateCanvas():

```
var img = new Image();
const ctx = this._CONTEXT;
const canvas = this._CANVAS;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this._CANVAS.width, this._CANVAS.height);
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";

img.onload = (() => {
  img.width = img.width;
  img.height = img.height;
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.strokeRect(100, 100, 400, 400);
  ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5); // this does nothing
});

img.src = (<any>window).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(path);
```

This draws the photo then the rectangle onto the canvas, however, the resulting image is too large to fit onto the screen, so I need to scale the canvas after all drawing is complete. I tried this with ctx.scale but the canvas remains the same size regardless of which values I specify.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot draw straight onto a photo, but what you can do is create an offscreen canvas that is the same size as the photo, draw the photo to it, and then draw your shapes on top.

The result can then be drawn to your main canvas e.g.

```
// Empty image for example purposes
const img = new Image(100, 100);

// Creating a canvas for example purposes
const mainCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const mainCtx = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

// Create an offscreen buffer
const bufferCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const bufferCtx = bufferCanvas.getContext('2d');

// Scale the buffer canvas to match our image
bufferCanvas.width = img.width;
bufferCanvas.height = img.height;

if (bufferCtx && mainCtx) {
  // Draw image to canvas
  bufferCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  // Draw a rectangle in the center
  bufferCtx.fillRect(img.width / 2 - 5, img.height / 2 - 5, 10, 10);

  // Draw the buffer to the main canvas
  mainCtx.drawImage(bufferCanvas, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. If I have a canvas in my html (<canvas #mainCanvas></canvas>), how do I update it to display mainCanvas object after it has been drawn?

Comment: I found a way to assign the mainCanvas object to the canvas in the html. However, I am having problems assigning a photo stored on the filesystem to the img object. I tried using just a string of the full path and filename + file extension, but that didn't work (InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0). I also tried img.src = (<any>window).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(path) but get the same error. I checked that the file exists by assigning it to an img tag in my html, and that works.

Comment: In my example I just create a canvas for `mainCanvas`, but this should be the canvas you already have that you want to draw to (you probably get this with `document.getElementById`).

Also, I create a blank image just for an example, you should be loading the image from the file system.

How are you currently trying to load the image?

Could you update your original question with some code examples please.

Comment: I have mostly solved this now, I think, please see code in edited post. I just need to figure out how to scale the canvas to the device screen size after all drawing is complete.

Comment: Ah, cool. So in order to draw your offscreen canvas to the main canvas while scaling it, you can simply supply a 4th and 5th argument to `drawImage` (width, and height). You'll want to figure out the aspect ratio of the original image / offscreen canvas (`height / width`), and then draw it back with the device width for the width, and device width times the aspect ratio for the height. Scale will be much harder to calculate, but you could still use this, you just need to scale the main canvas before you draw the offscreen canvas to it.

Comment: I don't think that's going to be a good solution, as I need the rectangle to be drawn on exact pixel coordinates onto the photo *before* any scaling takes place. I've seen some examples of HTML canvas being scaled by putting it in a div - is something similar perhaps possible in ionic?

Comment: That's fine, you just scale the offscreen canvas as you're drawing it to the main canvas. You can retain the aspect ratio, and it'll still be in the same place on the original photo.

Comment: I can give a full example a bit later if you like? (currently on my phone)

Comment: Yes please (to offer of example).

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. Here is a full example with a real image and scaling: https://codepen.io/jakesidsmith/pen/eqZyjm

I'll update my answer if this is the kind of thing you were looking for. :)

Comment: Thanks. The image scaling seems to work OK, but the position of the red box isn't correct when drawing on an image that's 400x700 with bufferCtx.fillRect(80, 80, 10, 10).

Comment: Actually, I'm guessing that the box is in the correct position, but the image cropping isn't correct, so the box ends up looking like it's in the wrong place?

Comment: Where do you want the image to be drawn? If you use exact coordinates it won't be in the right place when using different sized images. You should use values based on the image's width and height. Also, remember you'll have to remove half the rectangles width and height from these coordinates as the rectangle is drawn from its top left, not its center.